# Cannot convert undefined or null to object keycloak

Tags: keycloak

From Keycloak I got step by step for setting Identity Provider Redirector flow. I got the error "Cannot convert undefined or null to object"

Authentication -> Click Flows tab > Click browser-> Click setting icon in Identity Provider Redirector (1)->  Cannot convert undefined or null to object (2)

(1)
[image]

then I get an error as below (2)

[image]

I spent more time for searching the problem but I have no result. Could everyone help me!

Answer (score 3):

for anyone facing this issue, this is knowing bug at v19.
was fixed on v20.
upgrade your keycloak server to v20 and this issue will be gone.

[here](https://github.com/keycloak/keycloak-ui/issues/3375) details for the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you hit a known bug. Corrected in Keycloak 20.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: It seems to be hide bug of keycloak I built with latest keycloak version the error is removed